# HTML submit button sound issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to activate a sound when the user presses on my submit button. It seems that one must delay the operation of the button (otherwise the window is closed and there is no sound). With the default button I don't have this problem (i.e. when I delay the operation with setTimeout(), there is a sound and then a new window is opened) but not with submit button (is just moves to the defined window with the necessary parameters). How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<input class="window_change_button" type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="moveOn()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function moveOn(){
    buttonPressed();
}

function goBack(){
    buttonPressed("main.html"); 
}

function buttonPressed(nextWindowUrl){
    buttonPressedSound();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (nextWindowUrl){
            window.location.href = nextWindowUrl;
        }
        }, 100);
}

function buttonPressedSound(){
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/button_press.wav");
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: `type="button"`

Comment: I need that the button will be of type submit. @Rayon

Comment: `type="submit"` will unload the page hence nothing over JavaScript end will execute...

Comment: So there is no way to keep the functionality of submit form button and to allow sound on press? @Rayon

Answer (score 0):

Make a button with an onclick that triggers the audio recording using the JavaScript function.

***Run code snippet:***

```js
function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="clicksound.mp4"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I'm currently working on an web app for production tracking. In detail, I'm working on a small page which is running mostly on a handheld with barcode scanner (e.g. Zebra TC21 or TC26). The page is for tracking finished product and add them to stock.

Every time the form is submitted I want a beep sound played before the form submits.

I came up with this code.

```js
let audio = new Audio('/beep.mp3');
let form = null;
audio.onended = (event) => {
    if(form !== null) {
        form.submit();
    }
};

function beep(element) {
    form = element.closest('form')
    audio.play();

    return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" onclick="return beep(this);">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As I'm more a PHP Backend developer I know this code is not perfect but it works for me.

I'm happy to receive input on how to do it better.